# Whats wrong for this code for send email for android app

Tags: android, email, sendmail

the code this from a  https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-email-app-using-javamail-api-in-android-studio/:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    private String editTextEmail;
    private String editTextSubject;
    private String editTextMessage;
    private Session session;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void po(View view){
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    //Authenticating the password
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("my email", "passs");
                    }
                });
        try {
            //Creating MimeMessage object
            MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session);

            //Setting sender address
            mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress("my eamail"));
            //Adding receiver
            mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("to email"));
            //Adding subject
            mm.setSubject("Heloo ");
            //Adding message
            mm.setText("jabour");

            //Sending email
            Transport.send(mm);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}
and the error for run application run for Genymotion
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEgMH.png)

I've used it Debug 'app' this a Error

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: first.zerammar.com.fha, PID: 2090 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method op(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button' at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327) at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284) at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: What have you already examined yourself?

Comment: I'd suggest posting the stack trace, but once you look at that it'll probably answer the question for you.

Comment: I've used it Debug 'app' 
Error at the top